# jQuery: Open hash link relative to element id

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery like the following:

```
$(".show-quiz").click(function () {
        $(".quiz-container").fadeIn("fast");
    });
```

and a link would be like:

```
<a href="#quiz1" class="show-quiz">Show Quiz</a>
```

and on the page I would have a div like:

```
<div id="quiz1" class="quiz-container"></div>
```

What I want to do is modify the jQuery so that any link with a class of `show-quiz` shows the element with the id that matches the link href hash.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".show-quiz").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn("fast");
});
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/5gmde/)

Comment: How can I stop the hash being added to the address bar? Thanks

Comment: beat me to it:) an expanded example I was working on... http://jsfiddle.net/NdbRT/1/

Comment: @Luke: I know the feeling... :D